# ICO of 32-bit images

Tags: icons, conversion, 32-bit, imagemagick, inkscape

## Requirement

I'm using this shell script to create an ICO file to fulfill this requirement:

> Icons should be Windows .ico files and contain **32-bit** images in the following sizes: 16, 24, 32, 48, and 256.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "*** One way: use Inkscape ***"
inkscape -w 16 -h 16 -o 16.png icon.svg
inkscape -w 24 -h 24 -o 24.png icon.svg
inkscape -w 32 -h 32 -o 32.png icon.svg
inkscape -w 48 -h 48 -o 48.png icon.svg
inkscape -w 256 -h 256 -o 256.png icon.svg
magick convert 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 256.png icon.ico
magick identify icon.ico

echo "*** Other way ***"
magick convert -background none icon.svg -resize 16x16   -depth 32 16-32.png
magick convert -background none icon.svg -resize 24x24   -depth 32 24-32.png
magick convert -background none icon.svg -resize 32x32   -depth 32 32-32.png
magick convert -background none icon.svg -resize 48x48   -depth 32 48-32.png
magick convert -background none icon.svg -resize 256x256 -depth 32 256-32.png
magick convert -background none 16-32.png 24-32.png 32-32.png 48-32.png 256-32.png -depth 32 icon.ico
magick identify icon.ico

echo "*** Other way: simpler ***"
magick convert -background none icon.svg -define icon:auto-resize="256,48,32,24,16" -depth 32 icon.ico
magick identify icon.ico
```

## 32-bit?

But the output logs indicate that the created ICO files are all containing 8-bit sRGB images. How can I generate 32-bit ones?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's never any consistency in naming these. Every organisation seems to consider the numbering differently.

Your 32-bit file is really an 8-bit file.
Each channel uses 8 bits. You have 4 channels - Red, Green, Blue + Alpha.
4*8-bit channels = 32 bits.
A simple RGB file without alpha by the same token would be 3*8=24 bits.

See [RGBA colour model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model)

Comment: So, when the `magick convert` command reports `8-bit sRGB` it means 8 bits for each channel. And when it reports `16-bit sRGB` it means 16 bits for each channel. Right?

Comment: Yup. Your software isn't consistently naming. It's showing 8 or 16-bit, but then using a colour profile  description sRGB rather than a channel description RGBA.